# Automatically minimize desktop app window (or reset priority) on Windows machine

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, windows-7, skype

My organization utilizes a browser-based app (Chrome/Firefox) and Skype to allow kindergarten students to read books with adults, remotely.

One of the biggest problems we have happens with this scenario:

1. Tutor calls a dedicated Skype number that resides on student laptop (Windows 7)
2. Student answers Skype call
3. Skype application window remains open, blocking browser
4. Student does not know how to close Skype window
5. Student cannot see browser until support remotely connects to laptop and minimizes Skype window

Training the students, at that age, doesn't work. Teachers tell them not to mess with the laptops, anyways.

**So the question is this:**

Is there a way to automatically minimize Windows application windows via a custom script or is there a way to force browser windows to regain priority on the desktop based on certain triggers?

I'm looking more for pointers on where to do research or what to look at. I can probably build a solution if I know there's a tool or library where I can start.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to start Skype with the command line parameter

```
/minimized
```

That would start Skype minimized to the tray.

And on a second note I would imagine that when the kids can answer a Skype-call, they could be taught to press ALT+TAB after they have answered the call (and thereby switch to the browser).

You could also try http://ahkscript.org/ (Auto Hot Key) which is a scripting language for automation of common tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately, these kids are 5-6 years old and for a variety of reasons they are not allowed to touch the keys on the laptops. Thus, we need a hands-free way of minimizing the window.

Comment: OK! Then thats not an option. I'll dig in some old material I have on Windows Scripting Host and see if I can find anything. I think the biggest hurdle is to get the trigger "The incomming call has been answered".

Comment: I'm going to try to login remotely to one of our classroom laptops and try your /minimized suggestion, but I'll have to wait until Monday.